# Jquery Mask should allow maximum 3 places in decimal part

Tags: jquery, mask

I am using jQuery mask in one of my input field:

What I need is my input field should able to take maximum of 3 decimal places:

Suppose if I entered **3 it should get 3.000**

**5.2 -> 5.250
6.25->6.250**

What I did is as follows:

```
$('#test').mask('99.999');
```

In this it only take values like 12.355 like that.

My requirement is masking should allow maximum 3 places in decimal part and any value in integer part

Check my fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SCzVP/743/)

Comment: Can you show example with what you can't achieve? Do you want that 12.3 would be converted to 12.300 automatically?

Comment: @DmytroPastovenskyi I want to give a mask in input field like what I show in fiddle. But it should be able to take any value in integer places but a maimum of 3 places in decimal part! Hope you get it. It is about mask.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know how adamant you are about using that mask, but here's a jquery solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').on('change', function() {
      if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())){
        var value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(3);
        $(this).val(value);
      }
      else {
        $(this).val('');
      }     
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test"/>
```